# EF Core SQLite checking if table exists

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm attempting to check if a table exists in a SQLite database by executing a query using [EF Core 3.1 RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlRaw Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-3.1)

```
 var sql = $"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = '{GetTableName(table)}';";
 var result = Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql) ;
```

The result always returns

```
result = -1
```

This is the query normalized

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM sqlite_master 
WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'SendRequest';
```

The question is, why would the result from the `Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql)` return `-1`?

I don't see in the documentation what that means. I feel like it is throwing an error, but I haven't found any documentation to prove or disprove the thought.

When the same query is run in DB Browser for SQLite the query works perfectly fine:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database.ExecuteSqlRaw returns number of affected rows for UPDATE , INSERT and DELETE queries. It always returns -1 for SELECT. The method is not used for returning entities.

if you want to get some data using dbcontexe you can create stored procedure with output parameter that will return count.

Another way is to  create not mapped data set that will get return data and use FromSqlRaw to run a query.

create a new class

```
[NotMapped]
public class SpResult
{
public int TableCount {get; set;}
}
```

Add a new db set to dbcontext

```
  public virtual DbSet<SpResult> SpResults{ get; set; }
```

and query

```
var sql = $"SELECT COUNT(*) AS TableCount FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = '{GetTableName(table)}';";

var result = await _context.Set<SpResult>()
                 .FromSqlRaw(sql)
                .ToArrayAsync();

var tableCount=result.FirstOrDefault().TableCount;
```

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I started thinking but even the examples from the documentation use select Statements.

Comment: Is there no way to execute a select statement?

Comment: Thanks, this helps I was just reading on creating a custom entity type.  Appreciate the help

Comment: Pls let me if you have some problem. I worked a lot with .FromSqlRaw

Comment: I am using EF Core v3.1.13, Also better to add this line: `modelBuilder.Entity<SpResult>().HasNoKey();` at `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method in your DbContext class otherwise you will get: "Cannot create a DbSet for 'SpResult' because this type is not included in the model for the context." Exception.